# How to exit a child process and return its status from execvp()?

Tags: c, exec, fork, exit

In my simple custom shell I'm reading commands from the standard input and execute them with execvp(). Before this, I create a fork of the current process and I call the execvp() in that child process, right after that, I call exit(0).

Something like this:

```
pid = fork();

if(pid == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
}

if(pid == 0) {
    // CHILD PROCESS CODE GOES HERE...
    execvp(pArgs[0], pArgs);
    exit(0);
} else {
    // PARENT PROCESS CODE GOES HERE...
}
```

Now, the commands run with execvp() can return errors right? I want to handle that properly and right now, I'm always calling exit(0), which will mean the child process will always have an "OK" state.

How can I return the proper status from the execvp() call and put it in the exit() call? Should I just get the int value that execvp() returns and pass it as an exit() argument instead of 0. Is that enough and correct?

Comment: execvp will not return (unless pArgs[0] is not a valid executable file), so the exit(0) statement will never be reached.

Comment: "unless pArgs[0] is not a valid executable file" - there are a myriad of reasons why exec* may fail, that being only one. Permissions, resource counts, memory - errno will tell you.

Comment: And if the execvp() does fail, you should have exit(1) or exit(EXIT_FAILURE) or anything other than exit(0) - to indicate the failure.

Comment: Side note: you probably want [`_Exit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit) instead of `exit()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `waitpid(3)` or `wait(1)` in the parent code to wait for the child to exit and get the error message.

The syntax is:

```
pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);
```

or

```
pid_t wait(int *status);
```

`status` contains the exit status.  Look at the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) to see you how to parse it.

---

Note that you can't do this from the child process.  Once you call `execvp` the child process ***dies*** (for all practical purposes) and is *replaced* by the `exec`'d process.  The only way you can reach `exit(0)` there is if `execvp` itself fails, but then the failure isn't because the new program ended.  It's because it never ran to begin with.

**Edit:** the child process doesn't *really* die.  The PID and environment remain unchanged, but the entire code and data are replaced with the `exec`'d process.  You can count on *not* returning to the original child process, unless `exec` fails.

Comment: I do that already in the else { } I just didn't posted the code... But isn't the status always going to be 0 because of the exit(0)??

Comment: One last thing, if execvp() returned -1, should I do exit(0) or should I pass some other value to the exit() call?

Comment: Like exit(errno) is probably better, yes?

Comment: @Nazgulled: the only standard return values for a process are 0/EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE (stdlib.h). You can return other values but keep in mind that only the 8 least significant bits can be retrieved.

Comment: What should I return in exit() then?

Comment: @Nathan: the child process does not 'die' on execvp(); it changes from the original program to the new one, but the process ID is the same as before.  Die is done by exit or a signal - continuing to run with a new executable is definitely not dying.

Comment: For a really amusing way of doing it, I used to call vfork(), save the errno of execve() in a volatile variable that was initialized to zero, and check the value of the volatile variable in the parent process. Only works on some environments (including modern Linux).

Answer (score 3):

From your question it's a little hard to figure out what you're asking. So I'll try to cover a couple of the related issues:

- `execvp()` either does not return (on success), or it returns an error. Meaning your child code only need handle error conditions. Your child code should capture the result of `execvp()` and use that value in `exit()` as you suggested. Your child code should never return 0, since the only success means that the `execvp` worked and *that* processs will return 0 (or not).
- The parent can obtain child info from `waitpid()` about it's exit status. There are several macros defined to pull info from the returned `status` parameter. Notable for your purpose are `WIFEXITED` to tell you if the child exited "normally", and `WEXITSTATUS` to get the child's status as passed to `exit()`. See the `waitpid` man page for other macros.

Answer (score 3):

Use `wait()` or `waitpid()` in the parent process. An example here: [Return code when OS kills your process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742413/return-code-when-os-kills-your-process/747819#747819).

Also, when a child dies the `SIGCHLD` signal is sent to the parent process.