# Return code when OOM killer kills a process

Tags: linux, out-of-memory, waitpid, return-code

I am running a multiprogrammed workload (based on SPEC CPU2006 benchmarks) on a POWER7 system using SUSE SLES 11.

Sometimes, each application in the workload consumes a significant amount of memory and the total memory footprint exceeds the available memory installed in the system (32 GB).

I disabled the swap since otherwise the measurements could be heavily affected for the processes using the swap. I know that by doing that the kernel, through the OOM killer, may kill some of the processes. That is totally fine. The problem is that I would expect that a thread killed by the kernel exited with an error condition (e.g., the process was terminated by a signal).

I have a framework that launches all the processes and then waits for them using

```
waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
```

Even if a thread is killed by the OOM killer (I know that since I get a message in the screen and in /var/log/messages), the call

```
WIFEXITED(status);
```

returns one, and the call

```
WEXITSTATUS(status);
```

returns zero. Therefore, I am not able to distinguish when a process finishes correctly and when it is killed by the OOM killer.

Am I doing anything wrong? Do you know any way to detect when a process has been killed by the OOM killer.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742413/return-code-when-os-kills-your-process) asking pretty much the same question. However, since it is an old post and answers were not satisfactory, I decided to post a new question.

Comment: What about WIFSIGNALLED()? Is false?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Linux OOM killer works by sending `SIGKILL`. If your process is killed by the OOM it's fishy that `WIFEXITED` returns 1.

TLPI

> To kill the selected process, the OOM killer delivers a SIGKILL
>   signal.

So you should be able to test this using:

```
if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
    if (WTERMSIG(status) == SIGKILL)
        printf("Killed by SIGKILL\n");
}
```

Comment: That is what I expected, but after trying that it did not work. WIFSIGNALED(status) returns zero for all the processes (including the ones that were killed). Any idea?

Comment: @Victor Just for testing; try killing them with `kill(..., SIGKILL)`. See what happens.