# git error - can't push to github - pack-objects died of signal 9

Tags: git, github

I added some files to the repo, committed, and attempted to push to Github:

```
$ git add .  
$ git commit -m 'bla'  
$ git push origin master
```

I am getting an error when I try to push to Github.

```
Counting objects: 84, done.  
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.  
error: pack-objects died of signal 9  
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxxxx/xxxxx.git'
```

All was working fine before I went on vacation 2 weeks ago. Nothing has changed in the interim as far as I know.  The config file seems to be fine.  And git push -f also generates the same errors as above.

Comment: make sure that your ssh is set.

Comment: What do you mean?  SSH key?  It had been working fine.  Does that "expire" if not used for a couple weeks or something?

Comment: you have to set your ssh key to push to github. look at https://github.com/settings/ssh

Comment: Or have you now got some big files? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985124/git-push-error-index-pack-died-of-signal-9

Comment: It had been set.  I'd been using it for months with no problem.

Comment: There are no files over 10 megs except for a file within the .git directory -  .git/objects/pack/pack-xxxxxxxxxx.pack.  It's 421 Megs.  I would think Github could handle that, no?

Comment: FWIW, I tried adding the ssh key again and got "Key is already in use".

Comment: Sounds like you're getting hit by the [OOM killer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7180970/1256452).

Comment: Turns out @doctorlove was right.  There was a 101 Meg error log getting added.  Apparently, I'd added the error_log to .gitignore but never removed it from git cache so it was still getting tracked.  While I was on vacation, apparently the log topped the 100 Meg limit for the allowed file size.

Answer (score 72):

Try this:

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "32m"
```

```
pack.windowMemory::
    The maximum size of memory that is consumed by each thread
    in linkgit:git-pack-objects[1] for pack window memory when
    no limit is given on the command line.  The value can be
    suffixed with "k", "m", or "g".  When left unconfigured (or
    set explicitly to 0), there will be no limit.
```

Comment: ran into this problem on Cloud 9 workspace free account..Running this command worked!

Comment: Had a pack-objects died of signal 952 after running the command "git repack -a -d -f --window=250 --depth=250" on a newly constructed svn to git conversion, this fixed that is well. THANKS!

Comment: Neither this nor `git config --global pack.windowMemory "4096m"` made any difference to me.

Comment: This solved the problem on a tiny AWS t4g.nano instance I am using for testing.

Comment: Worked for me too. I was running out of space on a Raspberry pi due to a large .git folder. I ran this command and then git repack -a -d -f --depth=250 --window=250
 the .git folder after plugging the SD card into a PC. 
It shrank the .git folder from 3 GB to 1GB.

Answer (score 16):

Git repack organizes unpacked objects into packs, which are a collection of objects, individually compressed, with delta compression applied, stored in a single file, with an associated index file.

```bash
    git repack -a -d -f --window=0
```

- a: pack everything into a single pack
- d: remove any newly redundant
  packs
- f: don't reused old deltas, I guess to keep memory need down
- window=0: stops comparisons with other
  objects to try to save space, I guess also to keep memory need down

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and consider [providing some explanations along with your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), so that future users can follow your ideas/code more easily. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23943100)

Comment: This seems to be working for my bloated repo, unlike the most popular answer.

Comment: Someone please copy and paste the relevant parts from here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack (but it will make the post long).

Comment: Correction: this made no difference to the size of mine, though the command did complete successfully.

Comment: I have added some explanation to the answer (so am now getting the deserved downvotes - oops), but I don't think this actually fixes anything, it just re-attempts the pack operation that failed, with settings to try to use less memory.

Comment: Tried modifying all the git config suggestions given on related threads, but the error `error: pack-objects died of signal 9)` remained as it it. Finally this is the step that resolved exactly the same issue for me. 

I assume since it was failing at the packing step, a proper repack was what was needed. Not sure about the exact internal reason though.

Answer (score 3):

On a FreeBSD box with a lean RAM profile and a large repository with many files, I started getting this error.  The `/var/log/messages` file contained errors like this:

```
pid 93208 (git), jid 0, uid 1001, was killed: out of swap space
```

I was able to resolve this by [adding a little more swap space](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/adding-swap-space.html) temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite convinced you have a local problem and it's nothing to do with GitHub.
A git push consists of the following steps:

- local: delta compression of objects
- net: Writing new compressed objects to remote repo via SSH
- net: update refs in remote repo via SSH

Quite clearly, it's the first step that fails. You might be out of memory/swap?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because the **number of files** that I wanted to add exceeded **100**. If this is your problem you might want to push them in different commits.

Another explanation is that the files you want to push are too large.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the RAM usages, or create more space for swapfile

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in your `~/.git-support/hooks/` directory, or in the `.git/hooks` directory of your repo? In particular, file named `pre-push`?

If so, maybe you are seeing an error from something running during a pre-push [Git hook](https://githooks.com/). Experiment with renaming the file so that it does not execute. Restart your terminal and try committing again.

Answer (score -9):

Had this problem pushing to `Gitlab`.

Fixed it by adding `.*` to my `.gitignore`

i.e. ignored all files/folders e.g. `.git` beginning with `.`