# Upon git commit I see error `git-seekret died of signal 9`

Tags: git, github, git-commit, kill, sigkill

Any time I run `git commit` I get the following error:

```
error: git-seekret died of signal 9
```

This error occurs no matter what changes I am committing, small or large. It happens on all repos on my machine, a MacBook Pro running Ventura. It happens with all variations of the command, like `git commit -a` or `git commit filename` or even simply `git commit` with no args. It started happening randomly one day for no reason I can discern. Other git commands still work fine.

[Here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831788/git-error-cant-push-to-github-pack-objects-died-of-signal-9) and a few other places, people have asked about similar errors in connection to unusually large commits. None of the suggested fixes worked for me. My error occurs with a commit as small as a single character.

The menacing phrase "died of signal 9" appears to refer to the *nix kill signal. I am not sure what would be sending this signal. [A lack of RAM is one possible cause](https://www.reddit.com/r/gitlab/comments/h0ane4/error_shallowfile_died_of_signal_9/) but my MacBook's activity monitor shows a few gigs unused.

I don't know much about [git-seekret](https://github.com/apuigsech/git-seekret) nor why its running. It appears to no longer be maintained. There aren't clear instructions on how to remove it.

The command `which git` returns `git: aliased to hub`. I have reinstalled hub; this didn't fix it.

What other avenues can I explore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: I found a file called `~/.git-support/hooks/pre-commit` that contains the command `git seekret hook --run pre-commit`. This hook was running every time I attempted to commit. Removing or renaming this file eliminates the error.