# importing huge sql file using php command line

Tags: php, mysql, command-line

I have a php script that I run from ubuntu command line to read a huge xml file and insert it into a mysql db.

I tried the script on a small file and it works without problem.

```
php -f parse.php
```

The problem is when i tried to run it on the big xml file the script returns almost immediatly with the return :

```
Killed
```

Anyone have any suggestion how to run the script, or how to find what's the problem ?

Comment: maybe this can help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520194/php-script-is-killed-without-explanation

Comment: Are you Using SimpleXML or XMLReader to read the XML file?

Comment: Killed is the out of memory process running. try splitting the file or getting more ram

Comment: Please post some code, or a peek at the server error log or both. Without those we're just guessing.

Comment: I'm using SimpleXML, is XMLReader more performant ?

Comment: SimpleXML loads the entire file into memory before allowing you to process it: XMLReader is a [pull parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Pull_parsing) reading into memory only the current element that is being iterated over, so it is far more memory efficient

Answer (score 0):

You've exhausted the memory. You'll need to split up the xml file into more manageable pieces. You can also try running it on a machine with more ram.