# Laravel queues getting "killed"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue

Sometimes when I'm sending over a large dataset to a Job, my queue worker exits abruptly.

```
// $taskmetas is an array with other arrays, each subsequent array having 90 properties.
$this->dispatch(new ProcessExcelData($excel_data, $taskmetas, $iteration, $storage_path));
```

The `ProcessExcelData` job class creates an excel file using the [box/spout](http://opensource.box.com/spout/docs/) package.

- in the 1st example `$taskmetas` has 880 rows - **works fine**
- in the 2nd example `$taskmetas` has 10,000 rows - **exits abruptly**

*1st example - queue output with a small dataset:*

```
forge@user:~/myapp.com$ php artisan queue:work --tries=1
[2017-08-07 02:44:48] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessExcelData
[2017-08-07 02:44:48] Processed:  App\Jobs\ProcessExcelData
```

*2nd example - queue output with a large dataset:*

```
forge@user:~/myapp.com$ php artisan queue:work --tries=1
[2017-08-07 03:18:47] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessExcelData
Killed
```

I don't get any error messages, logs are empty, and the job doesn't appear in the `failed_jobs` table as with other errors. The time limit is set to 1 hour, and the memory limit to 2GBs.

Why are my queues abruptly quitting?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: @DaveCarruthers nope

Comment: `Killed` is coming from OS/shell probably out of memory for the process. pretty much the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/20520194/4233593

Comment: This particular case is because of job timeout in old laravel versions. Look at `$this->kill(1);` in `registerTimeoutHandler`

Answer (score 17):

You can try with giving a timeout.
For eg.
php artisan queue:work --timeout=120

By default, the timeout is 60 seconds, so we forcefully override the timeout as mentioned above

Comment: The time limit is set to 1 hour - the job dies within 5 minutes.

Comment: then in your case there might be some issue in the code or else memory issue

Answer (score 4):

By default **laravel has 90 sec of timeout** that can be seen in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts).

**In my case:**
I tried with customising **retry_after** value in `config/queue.php` but didn't work.
And than tried its alternative mentioned in the documentation **timeout** option with queue:work artisan command and that worked. so working artisan command is:

```
php artisan queue:work --timeout=900
```

In the above command I've increased the timeout to 15 min.

Comment: This was my case using redis.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not what you are looking for. but i have same problem and i think it's happen bcs of OS ( i will change it if i found the exact reason ) but lets check

```
queue:listen
```

instead of

```
queue:work
```

the main different between this two is that the queue:listen run Job class codes per job ( so you dont need to restart your workers or supervisor) but the queue:work use cache system and work very faster than queue:listen and OS can not handle this speed and prepare queue connection ( in my case Redis )

> queue:listen command will run queue:work in it self ( you can check this from your running
>   process in **htop** or .. )

But the reason of telling you to check queue:listen command , bcs of the **speed** . OS can work easily with this speed and have no problem to handle your queue connection and ... ( in my case there is no silent kill any more )

to know if you have my problem , you can **change your queue driver to "sync" from .env**   and see if it's kill again or not - if it's not killed , you can know that the problem is on preparing queue connection for use

- to know if you have memory problem run your queue with listen method or sync and php will return an Error for that, then you can increase your memory to test it again
- you can use this code to give more memory for testing in your code

  ```
  ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');//1 GIGABYTE
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you work with resource-intensive processes like image converting or BIG excel file creating/parsing. And timeout option is not enough for this. You can set `public $timeout = 0;` in your job but it still killed because of memory(!). By default memory limit is 128 MB. To fix it just add `--memory=256` (or heigher) option to avoid this problem.

BTW:

> The time limit is set to 1 hour, and the memory limit to 2GBs

This applying only for php-fpm in your case but not for queue process worker.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

I had a Supervisord job:

```
Job ID, Queue, Processes, Timeout, Sleep Time, Tries, Action Job_1,
Default, 1, 60, 3, 3
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#retrying-failed-jobs says:

> To delete all of your failed jobs, you may use the queue:flush
>   command:
>
> `php artisan queue:flush`

So I did that (after running `php artisan queue:failed` to see that there were failed jobs).

Then I deleted my Supervisord job and created a new one like it but with 360 second timeout.

Also important to remember was restarting the Supervisord job (within the control panel of my Cloudways app) and restarting the entire Supervisord process (within the control panel of my Cloudways server).

After trying to run my job again, I noticed it in the `failed_jobs` table and read that the exception was related to cache file permissions, so I clicked the Reset Permission button in my Cloudways dashboard for my app.