# Laravel Database Queue, "Killed" after a few seconds

Tags: php, laravel-5, vagrant, laravel-queue

i got a problem in my Laravel Project, i'm trying to **transcode a video** file with **FFMPEG** about *450MB* in size and due to this taking a **long** time i'm using Queues in Laravel to do this.

Due to the configuration of my production environment i have to use **database queues** the problem is that the queued job gets killed after about 60 seconds each time anytime i use the command `php artisan queue:work` in my *Vagrant* box.

The Vagrant box has 4GB of Ram available, 2D and 3D acceleration enabled and the `memory_peak_usage()` command never lists anything above 20MB during this whole process.

I checked the `php_sapi_name()` and it's **cli** as expected so it shouldn't have any limits at all when it comes to execution time, regardless i went to the cli *php.ini* file and removed any limits again to be certain.

Tried rebooting Vagrant, getting **Killed** after a few seconds anyways.

So i decided to try creating a Laravel **Command** for the transcoding process, i hardcoded the filepaths and stuff and lo and behold it's working without being **Killed**...

Am i missing something about Queues? I'm just running `php artisan queue:work` i'm not specifing a *timeout* of any sort, why is my queue getting killed?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: did you try with the `--timeout` param?

Comment: @Ali that's kind of the whole problem, i don't want **any** timeout at all, introducing one would break my application as ffmpeg can easily take like 1-2 hours to finish processing the videos.

I did read on the Laravel docs that the `--timeout` option would take precedence over regular timeouts on the cli... maybe if i set a massive one for my use case perhaps that would work out, but it's still nasty and doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61558770/9731538) answer. Probably you have to set memory limit option.

Answer (score 33):

The default timeout for jobs is 60 seconds, as you've found out. The timeout is specified with the `--timeout[=TIMEOUT]` property, and disabling the timeout entirely is done with `--timeout=0`.

```
php artisan queue:work --timeout=0
```