# returned non-zero exit status -9

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I am deploying code on elastic beanstalk and it gives me this error. I was using nginx proxy and elastic load balancer I disabled both and then try to deploy code this give me following error. I am unable to find any solution

> npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead   Not
>   using a reverse proxy   Running npm install: 
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.9.1-linux-x64/bin/npm
>   Setting npm config jobs to 1   npm config jobs set to 1   Running npm
>   with --production flag   Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for
>   more details.   UTC 2017/01/03 11:47:22 cannot find application npm
>   debug log at /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log 
>        Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in 
>         main()
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
>         node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
>         self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
>         raise e   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.9.1-linux-x64/bin/npm',
>   '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status -9
>   (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)

Comment: I have the same issue :( did you find a solution?

Comment: This warning means that old node-uuid module is deprecated and won't be maintained moving forward. So just do npm uninstall --save node-uuid and
npm install --save uuid

Comment: SSH to your node created by ELB and then run `sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install 2` manually and check what is wrong. There is more to this error then you get in the existing logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "return code" of -9 [indicates](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) that the process was killed with SIGKILL.  If you aren't doing that yourself, the [OOM killer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180970/return-code-when-oom-killer-kills-a-process) is a likely culprit.