# Parent trying to read children exit status (or return value), fork and wait

Tags: c, fork, solaris, wait, exit

I'm confused. Supposedly, basing on man, and many other sources, like this:
[Return code when OS kills your process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742413/return-code-when-os-kills-your-process/747819#747819)
wait(&status) should make it possible for me to get the exit status or return value of a child process?

Those 2 snippets of code, should allow me to see the exit value of it's child, and then print it.
child process function:

```
    int childFunction(char in[],char logPath[]){
        FILE *logFile= fopen( logPath, "a" );
        if(logFile==NULL)
        return 1;
        int c=system(in);
        fclose(logFile);
        return(c);
    }
```

and main:

```
        {...some unimportant code before this}
        result= fork();
        if(result==0){
            exit(childFunction(inLine,logPath));
        }
        else if(result>0){
            int status=0;;
            int c=(int)waitpid(-1,&status,0);
            printf("a:%d b:%d\n",status, WIFEXITED(status));
        else
            return -1;
        i=0;
```

I tried going with wait, sleeping for some time, exiting, returning, and read man page a few times. There either is a basic error in my understanding of this function, or after 4 hours of looking I simply no longer can see it.

SOLVED
For some reason, which i absolutely do not understand, if you change the `return(c)` in childFunction to `if(c!=)return(1);else return(0)` it will work. No idea why.

SOLVED 2
Okay, now I think I know why. See, it appears that either return call, or wait, reduces status to 8 most significant bits (256). What does that mean? That means, if you send normal int, the first bits are used, while the last 8 are discarded. At the same time, when I specify `return (1)` compiler automatically "shortens" the int to short int. Solution is to either return a short number, or do it like I did in previous "Solved" comment.

Answer (score 5):

the problem is you are not waiting for the child to exit

> ```
> int c=(int)waitpid(-1,&status,WNOHANG);
> ```

Here  the parent process checks if the child process has exited and if the child has not exited it returns.

In the above case, since you are opening a file in child process,there is a greater probability that there is a IO wait at child and so the parent process would be executed.

Now the parent process would check the status and since `WNOHANG` is used it will not be blocked at the waitpid and it continues and this is the reason you are not getting the correct status

I would suggest you use

> ```
> int c=(int)waitpid(&status);
> ```

Comment: Actually, I already edited that part in code. I started with what you are suggesting here, the same problem. Double checked now- except I put wait($status), the same problem.

Comment: can you be more clear in your problem that you are facing now ?

Comment: Okay, let's give an example. Let's say in="echo". The `childFunction()` will exit with `return 0` ,status will be equal to 0, c some number. At the same time, if I were to try in="blabla", `theChildFunction()` will exit with `return 255`. However, status will still be equal to 0! How to get the exit value from wait()

Comment: i think the problem with your code is the system system call. In case of correct execution the system call returns 0  and in case of error it returns -1 .To debug i would first suggest make your code working standalone ie call the function without fork and check if the return from the function is what you really want

Comment: Checked. Yes, the function returns proper value (255 actually, not -1).

Comment: While it did not solve the problem, I found that I have to use waitpid, for system() seems affect the result.

Comment: system() does the wait for you - it's a wrapper around a fork/exec/wait set of calls, so you can't wait for a system() generated process.